# How can I keep the selected tabs open when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

This is a side bar menu and until now it closes the tabs each time I reload the page and it's pretty annoying, what should I add to fix this?

[here is a code pen snippet](https://codepen.io/johan81/pen/moWEXP)

_menu.html.erb

```
<div  id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
 <button class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button>

    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <%= link_to "Journal", "#", class: "drop-item" %>
    <%= link_to "Stats","#", class: "drop-item" %>
    </div>

    <li class="dropdown-btn">Suppliers
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </li>

    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <%= link_to "Add a supplier", "#",  class: "drop-item" %>
        <%= link_to "Suppliers", "#",  class: "drop-item" %>
    </div>

    <%= link_to "Orders", "#",  class: "list-item" %>
    <%= link_to "Users", "#",  class: "list-item" %>
</div>
```

sidebar.js

*edit, added the whole code, I am not using the Bootstrap dropdown*

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

      if ($('.dropdown-btn')){
          activeTab = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].dataset.activeDropdown.myArticles
          sessionStorage.setItem('foo', activeTab);
      } 
      if(activeTab){
          $('#mySidepanel a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
      }
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    var i; 

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
      dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
      } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
      }
      });
    }
});


function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "180px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
```

### Update

I added this js code but I would need help :

```
$('.drop-item').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});

var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
    $('#mySidepanel a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: You can use localStorage to keep track of what was opened by user and then open those tabs when the page loads next time.

Comment: okay but how? please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the sessionStorage (I think that store for the session is enough for what you want to do).

On change on a tab, store the value of your tab (his ID for example):

`localStorage.setItem('tabId', 'foo');`

Then, on page load, if your key exists, open your tab. With jQuery, should be something like this:

```
$(function(){
   if (localStorage.getItem('tabId') !== null) {
      document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem('tabId')).show();
   }
}
```

To give you an idea. It's not the more cleaner as it is. For instance you should rewrite your `openNav` function to accept a param (the localStorage value)

Comment: I feel so uncomfortable with javascript... what should I change exactly in my code?

Comment: Don't worry, I was too, but Javascript is not so terrible. Your code doesn't work as it is? Do you have something in your console?

Comment: please put `console.log(activeTab);` before if statement

Comment: `console.log(activeTab);`returns  `null`

Comment: You have multiple items with the same href (#), you should set a data-attribute or an ID, will be cleaner. Also, i'm not sure if you're using the right way to get the value of the clicked link. Try to log `$(e.target).attr('href')` before `localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189583/discussion-between-johan-and-escanxr).