# How to keep the same tab open after refresh javascript / css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to keep selected tab active on refresh with css and js. Tried and checked with some question already been asked here but none of work for me. Don't know what to do.
html code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="title">Machine learning : Prediction ET0 </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'daily')" id="defaultOpen">Journalier</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hourly')">Horaire</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Exdaily')">Excel journalier</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Exhourly')">Excel Horaire</button>


      </div>
```

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, data) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");


  }
  document.getElementById(data).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `Tried and checked with some question already been asked here but none of work for me. ` Which are those questions/answers you tried and did not work ? Because first google search with " keep tab open with javascript stackoverflow " results in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039693/how-can-i-keep-the-selected-tabs-open-when-page-is-reloaded which is exactly what you need

Comment: Use the browser local storage to hold the selection, then when you open the browser again later and the JS runs when the DOM loads, set an `active` class to the setting you have in your localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the information about which tab should be active (or if a tab should be active at all) somewhere the browser can access it. There are multiple ways to achieve this via the [client-side storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage).

I would recommend to save the data in the browsers `localStorage`:

```js
// Execute this when a tab is clicked. `index` is the index of the clicked tab
// but you are free to use whatever identifier you like.
window.localStorage.setItem('activeTabIndex', index);
```

**Note:** Saving the `index` might not be the best approach since the order of tabs could change. Try to find an identifier that is unique and unlikely to change.

Then, on page load retrieve the saved data and "activate" the respective tab:

```js
const activeTabIndex = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTabIndex');

if (activeTabIndex) {
  // localStorage values are saved as strings so we have
  // to convert `activeTabIndex` to a number first.
  document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks')[Number(activeTabIndex)].classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: Should be noted: saving the index is only valid if the tabs will never change (always have the same tabs in the same order).

Comment: @Bar717 yep, you are absolutely right. Just added a note about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to store active tab and call function on page reload and set the button id with tab data string.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="title">Machine learning : Prediction ET0 </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'daily')" id="daily">Journalier</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hourly')" id="hourly">Horaire</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Exdaily')" id="Exdaily">Excel journalier</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Exhourly')" id="Exhourly">Excel Horaire</button>
      </div>
```

### Your Script should be like this

```
window.onload = function () {
       const activeTab = localStorage.getItem("activeTab");
       if(activeTab){
            // here your logic comes to show that specific tab add or remove class 
       } 
}
```

**Set the current tab on click event function like this**

```
localStorage.setItem("activeTab",data);
```

Comment below for any query thanks